# gnu screen losing DISPLAY connection

Tags: xorg, gnu-screen, ssh-tunnel, x11-forwarding

I ssh tunnel into a remote desktop running Ubuntu via a terminal - and use gnu screen
to do my work there. I have enabled X11 forwarding in my ssh config for the use
of X11 applications launched from one of screen's tabs.

Every few hours though, I cannot launch a new app (say for example emacs) - the message
is that connection to localhost:10 display failed.

So something that works when I reattach to a screen session stops working for a while.

Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have "trusted mode" (`ssh -Y` or `ForwardX11Trusted yes`) enabled?

Comment: @grawity: No - I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably caused not by Screen, but by the X11 security features in OpenSSH. By default, forwarded connections are in "untrusted" mode, with restricted access to certain features, and a time limit for the X11 authentication data.

Try enabling "trusted" mode by adding the `-Y` option to *ssh*, and/or the following into your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host yourserver
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Comment: Actually it turns out that even with trusted ssh tunnel, I am still losing the display connection. Any ideas as to how I may debug this?